Two or more user joins the voice call WebRTC
const socket = io();
const peers = {};
const localStream = new MediaStream();
const localAvatar = document.getElementById('local-avatar');
const camera = document.getElementById('camera');
const speed = 0.1; // Movement speed
startVoiceChat();

// Handle socket connection
socket.on('connect', () => {
    console.log('Connected to the server:', socket.id);
});

// Handle the current users list
socket.on('currentUsers', (users) => {
    Object.keys(users).forEach(userId => {
        if (userId !== socket.id) {
            createUserAvatar(userId, users[userId].position);
        }
    });
});

// Handle a new user joining
socket.on('userJoined', (data) => {
    createUserAvatar(data.id, data.position);
});

// Handle a user disconnecting
socket.on('userDisconnected', (data) => {
    const avatar = document.getElementById(data.id);
    if (avatar) {
        avatar.remove();
    }
});

// Handle position updates for other users
socket.on('userMoved', (data) => {
    const avatar = document.getElementById(data.id);
    if (avatar) {
        avatar.setAttribute('position', data.position);
    }
});

// Handle chat messages
socket.on('chatMessage', (data) => {
    const messagesDiv = document.getElementById('messages');
    messagesDiv.innerHTML += `<div><strong>${data.userId}:</strong> ${data.message}</div>`;
    messagesDiv.scrollTop = messagesDiv.scrollHeight; // Scroll to the bottom
});

function startVoiceChat() {
    const audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
    audioElement.autoplay = true;

    navigator.mediaDevices?.getUserMedia({ audio: true }).then((stream) => {
        const peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection();

        // Handle signaling messages for voice chat
        socket.on('signal', async (data) => {
            console.log(data);
            if (data.type === 'offer') {
                await peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(data));
                const answer = await peerConnection.createAnswer();
                await peerConnection.setLocalDescription(answer);
                socket.emit('signal', peerConnection.localDescription); // recent error
            } else if (data.type === 'answer') {
                await peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(data));
            } else if (data.candidate) {
                await peerConnection.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(data.candidate));
            }
        });

        stream.getTracks().forEach((track) => {
            peerConnection.addTrack(track, stream);
        });

        peerConnection.ontrack = (event) => {
            const remoteStream = event.streams[0];
            audioElement.srcObject = remoteStream;
            document.body.appendChild(audioElement);
        };

        peerConnection.onicecandidate = (event) => {
            if (event.candidate) {
                socket.emit('signal', { candidate: event.candidate });
            }
        };

        peerConnection.createOffer().then((offer) => {
            peerConnection.setLocalDescription(offer);
            socket.emit('signal', offer);
        });
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.error('Error accessing microphone:', err);
    });

    document.querySelector('#camera').setAttribute('voice-chat', '');
}

// Create an avatar for a user
function createUserAvatar(userId, position) {
    const avatar = document.createElement('a-entity');
    avatar.setAttribute('id', userId);
    avatar.setAttribute('obj-model', 'obj: #character;');
    avatar.setAttribute('position', `${position.x} ${position.y} ${position.z}`);
    avatar.setAttribute('scale', '0.3 0.3 0.3');
    avatar.setAttribute('rotation', '0 180 0');
    document.querySelector('a-scene').appendChild(avatar);
}

// Move the local avatar based on keyboard input
document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
    var position = camera.getAttribute('position');
    socket.emit('userMoved', { id: socket.id, position: position });
});

// Handle chat input
const sendButton = document.getElementById('send-button');
const chatInput = document.getElementById('chat-input');

sendButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const message = chatInput.value;
    if (message) {
        socket.emit('chatMessage', { userId: socket.id, message: message });
        chatInput.value = ''; // Clear the input field
    }
});

chatInput.addEventListener('keypress', (event) => {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
        sendButton.click(); // Trigger click event on Enter key
    }
});

// Handle box click event
const box = document.getElementById('clickableBox');
box.addEventListener('click', () => {
    socket.emit('message', 'Box clicked!'); // Send a message when the box is clicked
});

two people can voice call but three people shows this error
(index):156 Uncaught (in promise) InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'setRemoteDescription' on 'RTCPeerConnection': Failed to set remote answer sdp: Called in wrong state: stable
I am also trying to create a VR website with meetings that can handle large groups and i am stuck with two people. I cant seem to fix the problem. I need some help. testing it through localhost:3000.

Webrtc is not the right solution to manage large group of people connected together. Mostly depend on your internet connection, must have a large broadband. webrtc works fine only when you connect at most 3/4 people toghether. The right solution is to use a mediaserver. However this is my webrtc free solution for an audioconference with webrtc:
https://vrobbi-webrtc-demo.glitch.me/Audioconference.html     Hope this tip can help you
